# Arraylist of subclass can not be assigned to arraylist of superclass

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist, casting, extends

I have an array called grid, declared like this:

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Entity>>> grid;
```

And I try to set it like this:

```
grid = ctgf.blockMap;
```

where blockMap, inside of ctgf, is declared like this:

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Block>>> blockMap = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Block>>>();
```

And just for clarification the class Block is extend like this:

```
public class Block extends Entity{
```

Does anyone have any idea what I can do here?

Comment: Is `ArrayList<Block>` a subtype of `ArrayList<Entity>`?

Comment: What do you want to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem**

`ArrayList<Block>` does not extend `ArrayList<Entity>`. (I simplified a bit.)

Why not?

Try putting an `Entity` in a `ArrayList<Block>`.

```
new ArrayList<Block>().add(new Entity());
```

You can't do it! But any `ArrayList<Entity>` (or any subclass thereof) must be able to have `Entity`s inserted.

```
new ArrayList<Entity>().add(new Entity());
```

Thus, `ArrayList<Block>` can't be considered a subclass of `ArrayList<Entity>`.

**Solutions**

(1) You can declare `grid` as

```
public ArrayList<? extends ArrayList<? extends ArrayList<? extends Entity>>> grid;
```

The `?` in `? extends Entity` is a "wildcard". It means that the actual type is unknown, but it must extend `Entity`.

This may or may not be useful to you, since you will only be able to get `Entity`s from it (unless you cast after calling `get`), and you won't be able to add anything to it (since the actual type is unknown).

(2) Or you may decide what you actually want is a `ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Entity>>>`. In that case, it'll be verbose.

```
grid = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Entity>>>();
for(ArrayList<ArrayList<Block> blockList1 : ctgf.blockMap) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Entity>> entityList1 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Entity>>();
    for(ArrayList<Block> blockList2: blockList1) {
        entityList1.add(new ArrayList<Entity>(blockList2));
    }
    grid.add(entityList1);
}
```

Comment: I like your second solution, but does casting it make sense?

Comment: +1 No problem :) Going to delete my answer now, as it seems obsolete.

Comment: It didn't work. I changed the grid declaration, but I'm getting the same error.

Comment: @PaulDraper Now it gives me `Incompatible types.
Required:
ArrayList
<java.util.ArrayList<Entity>>
Found:
ArrayList
<Entity>`, and I have no idea how your for loops work, I haven't been taught that yet in HS Programming 2.

Comment: @AidanEdwards, I believe your last comment was about the second solution? I fixed that too.